# Oracle: Execution plan: is it reliable?

Tags: performance, oracle

Look at the following execution plan.
It says Oracle will start with an index range scan...
But it's impossible because he doesn't have any value to look for since it reads this values from the ENI_TAVOLO_ETL_DETT table.

Is the execution plan not saying the truth?

[image]

the query is:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
          DTSC.TSC_ETL_ID "Tavolo ETL",
          DTSC.TIPO_PROCESSO_COD "TIPO_PROCESSO",
          dtsc.PUNTO_EROGAZIONE_COD "PUNTO_EROGAZIONE",
          DTSC.FORNITURA_OLD_COD "FORNITURA",
          DTSC.SOGGETTO_COD "SOGGETTO",
          DTSC.CONTO_CLIENTE_COD "CONTO_CLIENTE",
          (SELECT f1.eif_campo24
             FROM etl_elab_interf_flat f1
            WHERE     f1.eif_campo198 = DTSC.id_messaggio
                  AND f1.idde_identif_dati_ext_id = DTSC.idde_identif_dati_ext_id
                  AND f1.eif_campo200 = 'FORNITURA_ENI'
                  AND f1.eif_campo29 = 'Nuovo')
             "C_ORD_IT",
          (SELECT TO_CHAR (
                     TRUNC (DataCompetenzaProcesso (dtsc.id_messaggio,
                                                    dtsc.idde_identif_dati_ext_id,
                                                    dtsc.tipo_processo_cod,
                                                    c.pia_pod_attesa_id)),
                     'DD/MM/YYYY')
             FROM eni_flussi_hub c
            WHERE     c.flh_id_messaggio = dtsc.id_messaggio
                  AND dtsc.idde_identif_dati_ext_id = c.idde_identif_dati_ext_id)
             "DATA COMPETENZA",
          DTSC.id_messaggio "ID_MESSAGGIO",
          --       ParseError (dtsc.mon_desc_errore_siu) "Tipo errore",
          REPLACE (REGEXP_REPLACE (dtsc.mon_desc_errore_siu,
                                   '&#xA;- StackTrace&#xA;.*',
                                   '',
                                   1,
                                   0,
                                   'imn'),
                   '&#xA;',
                   ' ')
             "Errore",
          dtsc.IDDE_IDENTIF_DATI_EXT_ID
     FROM SIUINTEGRA.ENI_TAVOLO_ETL_DETT DTSC
    WHERE     1 = 1
          AND DTSC.DTSC_TAVOLO_DETT_ID = DTSC.DTSC_STORICO_ID
          AND DTSC.DTSC_DATA_FIN = TO_TIMESTAMP ('31-DIC-9999 00:00:00')
          --
          AND dtsc.tipo_processo_cod IN
                 ('CC',
                  'NUOVA_ATT_ENI',
                  'VOLTURA_ATT',
                  'VOLTURA_ENI',
                  'AT',
                  'VT',
                  'CC_POWER',
                  'VOLTURA_ATT_PWR')
          AND EXISTS
                 (SELECT 1
                    FROM NETATEMP.TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013_UFF p
                   WHERE p.id_messaggio = DTSC.id_messaggio);
```

Plan in text format

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 205  Bytes: 758  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 82.337.155  IO Cost: 199  Time: 3                    
    2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIUETL.ETL_ELAB_INTERF_FLAT Object Instance: 1  Filter Predicates: "F1"."EIF_CAMPO198"=:B1 AND "F1"."EIF_CAMPO200"='FORNITURA_ENI' AND "F1"."EIF_CAMPO29"='Nuovo'  Cost: 6  Bytes: 27  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 103.802  IO Cost: 6  Time: 1               
        1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SIUETL.ETL_EIF_FK_IDX4 Search Columns: 1  Access Predicates: "F1"."IDDE_IDENTIF_DATI_EXT_ID"=:B1  Cost: 4  Cardinality: 9  CPU Cost: 40.772  IO Cost: 4  Time: 1           
    4 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIUINTEGRA.ENI_FLUSSI_HUB Object Instance: 2  Filter Predicates: "C"."IDDE_IDENTIF_DATI_EXT_ID"=:B1  Cost: 4  Bytes: 21  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 40.070  IO Cost: 4  Time: 1                  
        3 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SIUINTEGRA.ENI_FLH_IDX6 Search Columns: 1  Access Predicates: "C"."FLH_ID_MESSAGGIO"=:B1  Cost: 3  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 29.429  IO Cost: 3  Time: 1           
    12 HASH UNIQUE  Cost: 205  Bytes: 758  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 82.337.155  IO Cost: 199  Time: 3                  
        11 NESTED LOOPS             
            9 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 204  Bytes: 758  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 69.141.535  IO Cost: 199  Time: 3          
                6 SORT UNIQUE  Cost: 35  Bytes: 611.020  Cardinality: 61.102  CPU Cost: 8.113.248  IO Cost: 34  Time: 1     
                    5 INDEX FAST FULL SCAN INDEX NETATEMP.TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013_UFF2 Cost: 35  Bytes: 611.020  Cardinality: 61.102  CPU Cost: 8.113.248  IO Cost: 34  Time: 1  
                8 INLIST ITERATOR   
                    7 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SIUINTEGRA.ENI_DTSC_UK4_IDX Search Columns: 2  Access Predicates: "P"."ID_MESSAGGIO"="DTSC"."ID_MESSAGGIO" AND ("DTSC"."TIPO_PROCESSO_COD"='AT' OR "DTSC"."TIPO_PROCESSO_COD"='CC' OR "DTSC"."TIPO_PROCESSO_COD"='CC_POWER' OR "DTSC"."TIPO_PROCESSO_COD"='NUOVA_ATT_ENI' OR "DTSC"."TIPO_PROCESSO_COD"='VOLTURA_ATT' OR "DTSC"."TIPO_PROCESSO_COD"='VOLTURA_ATT_PWR' OR "DTSC"."TIPO_PROCESSO_COD"='VOLTURA_ENI' OR "DTSC"."TIPO_PROCESSO_COD"='VT')  Cost: 9  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 162.886  IO Cost: 9  Time: 1  
            10 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIUINTEGRA.ENI_TAVOLO_ETL_DETT Object Instance: 3  Filter Predicates: "DTSC"."DTSC_TAVOLO_DETT_ID"="DTSC"."DTSC_STORICO_ID" AND "DTSC"."DTSC_DATA_FIN"=TO_TIMESTAMP('31-DIC-9999 00:00:00')  Cost: 10  Bytes: 748  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 173.206  IO Cost: 10  Time: 1
```

Comment: are you sure there isn't an index on the following column, f1.idde_identif_dati_ext_id ? Check the definition of etl_elab_interf_flat table, the plan indicates what appears to be a foreign key index called ETL_EIF_FK_IDX4. Basically the plan indictaes the sub-select will be run against ENI_TAVOLO_ETL_DETT table first, prior to applying the remaining predicates

Comment: yes. There is the index on etl_elab_interf_flat for the field in FK idde_identif_dati_ext_id. But I don't understand why it says it use that index as first thing. When the first thig it does should be to read the ENI_TAVOLO_ETL_DETT

Comment: @Sam it seems like execution plan should be interpreted in a slightly different way in case you have scalar subqueries in your query. I had exactly the same question some time ago and surprisingly I wasn't able to find any official explanation of this, even on MOS. probably I didn't look hard enough though.

Comment: Can you please post your DDL's so that we can simulate?

Comment: Can you print the text version of the plan, as output by DBMS_Xplan.display()?

Comment: DDL is very long ad each table has some million record.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of be here now is correct.

The query plan shows scalar subqueries first, although they are executed **after** a record was fetched from the driving query. Today I've learned that the cost of these subqueries is not even considered in the total cost, because Oracle doesn't know how many times they're executed, see [Scalar Subselect Costing](http://orastory.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/scalar-subselect-cost-accounting/)

Comment: really really interesting... I make a large usage of scalar subquery and functions in query. I'd like to know how to speed up and to parallelize this two operations..

Comment: IMO, the most promising way to optimze PL\SQL is to replace it by SQL (Joins and CASE).

Answer (score -1):

Oracle engine now uses cost based optimizer which creates its execution plan based on stats gathering. Based on these stats oracle engines gets hold of amount of data it has to deal with and it creates plan accordingly.
Point i am making is execution plan is never fixed unless you force it, it will be based of table stats gathered by oracle. If your stats are stale then execution plan will go haywire.

Stats are gathered by DBAs by running background jobs or you can trigger it manully as well.

Earlier oracle used to have rule based optimizer so stats were not in picture.

Just to summarise, my point is execution plan is not fixed and heavily dependant on stats.

You can read more about stats here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/stats.htm